# Frontend minimize load time

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, load-time

I am using new-relic and for my website, the homepage is taking 8 seconds on average to be fully loaded. The network requests are fast, but the dom and page rendering are whats slowing it down. I have google +, facebook, twitter share buttons and bxslider.

When I run it in my browser it takes 2-4 seconds. I am not very familiar with how to optimize frontend performance. I am pretty shocked it is taking that long.

If anyone could give me tips to speed it up; that would be great.

I tried to figure out how to use google chrome profiler tool, but it says 80% idle.

The website is http://phppointofsale.com

[image: Screnshot]

- Brown is network
- Yellow is DOM
- Blue is page rendering

Comment: The network part of the web site is fast, it is the dom loading and page rendering that is the problem.

Comment: I added the profiling for last 7 days

Comment: I've noticed (in one of my earlier projects) quite some annoying slowdowns when using Google+ and Facebook buttons, although your graph doesn't seem to indicate this. But when I load your website, I see it, fully rendered and working well within 3 seconds. And that's on a laptop of over 3 years old, which could use some reinstalling anyway.

Comment: Do you think the profiling tool might have issues? I just tried on a 4 year old computer and was under 4 seconds

Comment: B.t.w. I tried in Chrome and IE. Maybe IE was slightly slower, but still nowhere near 10 seconds.

Comment: Similar results here. I'm getting the page fully rendered and functional within 2 seconds.

Comment: what profiling tool are you using?

Comment: The first time i visited the page, the page itself took 5 seconds to leave the "waiting" phase, however, after that first load, all of the loads were far quicker than that. Was unable to recreate it taking longer.

Comment: Well just to bring in a different observation: It takes 4–6 seconds for me everytime I load the webpage (for a *full* load).

Comment: Another observation using Chrome's Dev Tools: 60–70% of that time is spent on Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the profiling tool you are using might have issues. In my PC (Windows 7, Chrome 34.0.1847.131) your website loaded in more or less 2 seconds. So i run some tests with various tools to see what is going on.

1. [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/)
   [image]
   As you can see the load time is 1.2 seconds and your site is 85% faster of all tested sites. The most load time is taken by `plusone.js` which is 247ms and `jquery.bxslider.js?v=1.0` , `jquery.fitvids.js?v=1.0` , `jquery.slicknav.min.js?v=1.0` , `functions.js?v=1.0` each of them take 227ms.
   Time spent per Content:
                       -Script 39.44%
   -Image  37.75%
   -HTML   12.67%
   -Other  7.45%
   -CSS    2.69%

   Time spent per Domain
   -phppointofsale.com 51.40%
   -apis.google.com    8.01%
   -www.facebook.com   6.80%
   -themes.googleuser… 5.83%
   -static.xx.fbcdn.net    4.01%
   -other  23.95%
   [Here](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dJtj0w/http://phppointofsale.com/) you can see the results by yourself.
2. [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)
   [image]
    This tool gives your pageload 3secs
   [Here](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/phppointofsale.com/e3oZyOlh) you can see the results by yourself.
3. [Loadimpact](http://loadimpact.com/)
   [image]
    This tool also gives(as the first one) a load time of 1.3secs.
   [Here](http://loadimpact.com/test/view/1673790) you can see the result by yourself

---

Now the are some technics that you can use to speed up your site. Based on the previous tools i would suggest specific for your site:

1. Minify CSS
   Example:[Your](http://phppointofsale.com/css/base.css?v=1.0) CSS could be minified to [this](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/phppointofsale.com/e3oZyOlh/pagespeed/base_92fcfd0d50b9a47d2da2a765029e1df0.css) and you have 25% size reduction.
2. Specify image dimensions
   Example:`<img class="feature-img scale" src="img/multiple_devices.png" alt="">` is missing width and height attributes
3. Minify JavaScript.
   Example: Your JS could be minified to [this](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/phppointofsale.com/e3oZyOlh/pagespeed/jquery.tipsy_7fb5d105c6fe85a45f77ac9a42d4331c.js) and you have 44% size reduction.
4. Make fewer HTTP requests
   This page has 22 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one. This page has 8 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
5. Leverage browser caching
   Some cacheable resources (as [this](http://phppointofsale.com/img/social/icon-twitter.png) one) have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future.
6. Add Expires headers
   There are 44 static components (as [this](http://phppointofsale.com/css/style.css?v=1.0) one) without a far-future expiration date

These and many more information you can get tehm from the links provided.

Answer (score 3):

From visiting your site I think your reports are being skewed from the calls to your adroll.com and social media. A good tool to use here is YSlow: I ran it quick on your site and this would be the one I would address first:

```
Grade F on Make fewer HTTP requests
This page has 21 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
This page has 8 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Understand the best practices fundamentals, reading:

   - The legendary Yahoo article [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). Yahoo based his performance tool [YSlow](https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) on that article.
   - Article by Google Developers: [Web Performance Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro)
2. There are several other diagnosis tools like [Google Chrome Audit Panel](http://imgur.com/pJR8xd3). Firefox and IE have similar tools.
3. Use a tool for automatize these main good practices. Two good tools for that are: [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/). Here you have an [introduction to Gulp](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/).
4. I checked you site right now and these are some YSlow recomendations:

   - This page has 19 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one (you can do this with Grunt.js or Gulp.js).
   - This page has 8 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one (you can do this with Grunt.js or Gulp.js).
   - Add Expires headers. There are 45 static components without a far-future expiration date (mainly css, js and images.you can do this in several [ways](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires)).
   - Compress components with gzip. There are 21 plain text components that should be sent compressed. You can do this sending a [http request for gzip](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip).

There are some others but those are the principals.

In conclusion the main recomendation is to minify and join: all css files in 1 file, all js files in 1 file, and all images you can in 1 [css sprite](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). This is better done with Gruntjs or Gulpjs but if you need a quick and dirty way, you can use online tools like:

- [Jscompress](http://jscompress.com/)
- [Instant Sprite](http://instantsprite.com/)

Answer (score 1):

**As an additon to @McCheesiIt's answer +1**

1. Using bxslider, try to add the property `preloadImages`

   ```
   $('#features').bxSlider({
       auto: true,
       pause: 8000,
       preloadImages: 'all' // or 'visible'
   });
   ```
2. Put your `<script></script>` tags in the `<head>` section or just before the closing body tag `</body>`

BTW: I have a very slow DSL line (8'000Kbytes DL / 15Kbytes UL) and your site loaded in 3.00 seconds, which is acceptable.